# Why am I getting alot of exceptions processing jpeg image byte streams

Tags: c#, image, jpeg, aspose

I am trying to use Aspose.Imaging version 21.7.0 to compress some .jpg and .png byte arrays.

My Winforms Click event:

```
    private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _context.Images.Load();

        var images = _context.Images.Local.ToBindingList();
        
        foreach (var image in images)
        {
            if (image.ImageData != null)
            {
                image.MimeType = MimeTypes.GetMimeType(image.Filename.Trim());
                if (image.MimeType.StartsWith("image") && image.MimeType != "image/vnd.microsoft.icon")
                {

                    byte[] newImage;
                    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(image.ImageData))
                    {
                        using (RasterImage myImage = (RasterImage) Image.Load(stream))
                        {
                            switch (image.MimeType)
                            {
                                case "image/png":
                                    PngOptions options = new PngOptions
                                    {
                                        CompressionLevel = 9,
                                        ColorType = PngColorType.IndexedColor,
                                        Progressive = true,
                                        Palette = ColorPaletteHelper.GetCloseImagePalette(myImage, 256,
                                            PaletteMiningMethod.Histogram)
                                    };

                                    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
                                    {
                                        myImage.Save(memory, options);
                                        memory.Position = 0;
                                        newImage = memory.ToArray();
                                    }

                                    break;
                                case "image/jpeg":
                                    JpegOptions saveOptions = new JpegOptions
                                    {
                                        BitsPerChannel = 8,
                                        CompressionType = JpegCompressionMode.Progressive,
                                        Quality = 100,
                                        ResolutionSettings = new ResolutionSetting(96.0, 96.0),
                                        ResolutionUnit = ResolutionUnit.Inch,
                                        ColorType = JpegCompressionColorMode.Cmyk,
                                        Palette = ColorPaletteHelper.GetCloseImagePalette(myImage, 256, PaletteMiningMethod.Histogram)
                                    };

                                    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
                                    {
                                        Debug.WriteLine(image.Filename);
                                        try
                                        {
                                            myImage.Save(memory, saveOptions); <<== Exceptions
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception exception)
                                        {
                                            Debug.WriteLine("Image Byte Array: " + image.ImageData);
                                        }
                                        
                                        memory.Position = 0;
                                        newImage = memory.ToArray();
                                    }

                                    break;
                                default:
                                    newImage = null;
                                    break;
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }

                    image.CompressedImageData = Compress(newImage);
                }
                else
                {
                    image.CompressedImageData = null;
                }
            }
        }

        var count = _context.SaveChanges();

        MessageBox.Show($@"{count} images compressed.");
    }
```

I am getting alot of Exceptions with jpeg images. Example:

> Exception thrown: '   ' in Aspose.Imaging.dll

> Exception thrown: 'Aspose.Imaging.FileFormats.Dng.DngException' in Aspose.Imaging.dll

> Exception thrown: '   ' in Aspose.Imaging.dll

> Exception thrown: 'Aspose.Imaging.CoreExceptions.ImageSaveException' in Aspose.Imaging.dll

... all thrown from `myImage.Save(memory, saveOptions)` in the jpeg section.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First hint: when you catch an exception, log the full details. This statement: `Debug.WriteLine("Image Byte Array: " + image.ImageData);`... tells you *nothing* about the exception that has been thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **Aspose.Imaging** is a paid product,
you should contact them at their site for support.

There is a free forum specially for Aspose products:
https://forum.aspose.com/

Everyone that have experienced with Aspose errors know that the errors are hard to understand due to their **obfuscation** of the code, so the best solution is to contact them directly.

Comment: I have opened an Incident with Aspose.